# Sort images by rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Every picture has a rating from 1 to 5. I want to sort them by rating (for example: every picture with rating 5 shows on top, with rating 4 under 5, etc.)

Comment: Are the ratings just a number in the AR object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it should be as simple as

```
@pictures = Picture.order("rating DESC")
```

Comment: The call to `all` isn't needed, you can call order directly on `Picture`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `default_scope`... http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

`default_scope :order => 'rating DESC'`

Then in your controller:
`@pictures = Picture.all`

Comment: it works too!, Thanks dennismonsewicz!, and thanks for the apidock.com site.